# Jobs not processing, how do I loading additional classes into Delayed_Job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, configuration, delayed-job, koala

I am trying to offload any api calls to delayed_job to make my site more responsive. Some examples would be kissmetrics logging or post to facebook.

After some mucking about I figured out that the jobs are not being processed and that I need to explicitly require the classes in the initializers/delayed_jobs_config.rb thanks to:

[Rails Delayed Job & Library Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569396/rails-delayed-job-library-class)

[delayed_job and rails 3 not loading jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669699/delayed-job-and-rails-3-not-loading-jobs)

However, I'm still not sure how to require these gems. Please provide an example if possible for 'Koala', 'KM', or anything really.

Answer (score 1):

in `initializers/delayed_jobs_config.rb`

```
require "koala"
```

If that does not help you, take a look at `threadsafe!`

> Rails does not eager load classes if the app is loaded via a rake
>   task (and that's how DJ does its thing).

if you have that line un-commented for your environment, then I would remove that for delayed_jobs.  You can accomplish that with

```
config.threadsafe! unless defined?($rails_rake_task) && $rails_rake_task
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12570405/643500