# Ruby on Rails - Delayed job - Jobs queue are not adding in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

Jobs queue are not adding in delayed_jobs table, when it is daemonized. But that works when it is not daemonized.

I have three rake tasks(a.rake, b.rake, c.rake).

**In a.rake**

```
task :run_a => :environment do
  A.new.get_a_data
end

class A
 def get_a_data
   ...
   schedule_next_a_job
 end

 def schedule_next_a_job
   get_a_data
 end

handle_asynchronously :get_a_data, :run_at => Proc.new { 2.minutes.from_now }, :queue => 'a'
end
```

**In b.rake**

```
task :run_b => :environment do
  B.new.get_b_data
end

class B
 def get_b_data
  ...
  schedule_next_b_job
 end

 def schedule_next_b_job
   get_b_data
 end

handle_asynchronously :get_b_data, :run_at => Proc.new { 5.minutes.from_now }, :queue => 'b'
end
```

**In c.rake**

```
namespace :run do
  task :start do
  `rake run_a`
  `rake run_b`
  if Rails.env == 'development'
    `QUEUES=a,b rake jobs:work`
  else
    `RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job --queues=a,b start` 
  end

  task :stop do
  `rake jobs:clear`
  end
end
```

**In console, i run like below:**

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake run:start # to start jobs worker
rake run:stop # to clear my jobs worker
```

**In my delayed jobs table last_error is showing as:**

> Job failed to load: undefined class/module A
>
> Job failed to load: undefined class/module B

Can anyone help me to get rid of this problem?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you check out this [Solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518529/model-classes-not-loading-in-delayed-job-when-using-threadsafe#answer-12570405) ??

Comment: @Gagan Yes. require 'my_custom_class' works!. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One common cause of deserialization errors is that the YAML references a class not known to the worker. If this is the case, you can add

```
# file: config/initializers/custom.rb
    require 'my_custom_class'
```

which will force `my_custom_class` to be loaded when the worker starts. **[Reference](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/wiki/Common-problems#jobs-are-silently-removed-from-the-database)**